# Cython: pass data as user-defined type

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a C++ SDK that I'm trying to write a Python wrapper for. In the header, there's a class `Packet` that's mentioned but never expounded upon, and there's also a `Sensor` class that is. This latter class has a method that takes an object of the former, like

```
...
class Packet
...
namespace space {
    class Sensor {
    ...
    void processPacket(Packet& packet);
    ...
    }
}
```

My question is how do I get Python data into this `processPacket` method? I don't have access to the SDK source code. So far, I've got

```
from cython.operator import dereference


cdef extern from "Sensor.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Packet:
        pass


cdef extern from "Sensor.hpp" namespace "space":
    cdef cppclass Sensor:
        Sensor() except +
        ...
        void processPacket(Packet &packet)


cdef class PyPacket:
    cdef Packet *thisptr


cdef class PySensor:
    cdef Sensor *thisptr
    ...
    def process_packet(self, PyPacket packet):
        self.thisptr.processPacket(dereference(packet.thisptr))
```

It compiles, but when I try to pass data into it with

```
sensor = Sensor(...)
data = b'...'
wrapped_data = PyPacket(data)
sensor.process_packet(wrapped_data)
```

I get a segmentation fault.

#### Update

By changing the method to

```
    def process_packet(self, PyPacket packet):
        self.thisptr.processPcapPacket(<PcapPacket&> packet)
```

it seems to be working. *fingers crossed*

Comment: It looks like you're doing the right thing. There's nothing obviously wrong. I don't think there's enough information here for anyone to work out what's going wrong

Comment: After some more digging, it looks like the Packet pointer isn't getting initialized, which may be the issue, though I'm not yet sure how to feed bytes into PyPacket to do that. (`def print(self): print(<uintptr_t>self.thisptr)` prints 0.)